# Deriving equation by weights and biases from a neural network

Tags: neural-network

I carried out a neural network with a large database and got great answer in testing it (very small error - nearly 4%). Now I want to using weights and biases to derive an equation in order to get my outputs directly (without usage of that network again). How can I derive an equation to get my outputs?

Answer (score 1):

Well it depends on which kind of neural network you are using.
If it's a simple feedforward network, then all you need to do to derive your formula is to propagate your inputs with the weight matrices and the bias vectors through the activation functions.

Let's say you have an SLFN (Single Layer Feedforward Network) which basically means you have an input layer, a hidden layer and an output layer.

Let's denote the:

- input vector **X**
- weight matrix between input and hidden **W_ih**
- bias vector on hidden layer **b**
- activation function on hidden nodes **f**
- output of the hidden layer **Y_h**
- weight matrix between hidden and output **W_ho**
- output vector **Y**

The steps to compute your output are:

**1-** Propagate your input vector through the connections to the hidden layer and add the bias terms. This gives you the total input **Z** "entering" the hidden layer (which is sometimes called the "logit"):

> **Z = X * W_ih + B**

where **B** is the matrix that has every row equal to the vector **b**, and as many rows as you have input cases.

**2-** Apply the activation function to this logit:

> **Y_h = f(Z) = f(X * W_ih + B)**

**3-** Propagate once more this vector through the connections to the output layer and your output vector **Y** is equal to:

> **Y = Y_h * W_ho = f(X * W_ih + B) * W_ho**

Now if you have more hidden layers, all you have to do is repeat steps 1 and 2 for every additional hidden layer and end with step 3 for your output layer.

Comment: Hi Dear Dolma , thans a lot for your help.you know really i did this procedure but when i test it saw incorrect answer. i don't know whats the problem. please explain me about weights. i think series of weights that i used have special sequence.when we have for example six inputs and 4 neurons in hidden layer and one or three outputs, how can i recognize weight index to know for which neuron. in factual, i want to know when i have 24 weights, which weight is for which neuron and input. with knowing it we can use of this algorithm. thanks a lot, I'm waiting for your answers.

Comment: Well if you have 24 weights, 6 inputs and 4 hidden nodes, it means those are all your weights from input layer to hidden layer. Now from what I understand your weights are not in matrix form but instead in an array. You can have two situations, the first would be that your weights are arranged by "origin" which means that the first 4 weights are from input node 1 to all 4 hidden nodes, the next 4 are from input node 2 to all 4 hidden nodes, etc. The other possibility would be that they are arranged by "destination", then the first 6 weights are from all 6 input nodes to hidden node 1, etc.

Comment: Then all you'll have to do is reshape your array to get your matrix. Although you can't just guess it out of nowhere. So it would help if you have some info about how your code works. Is it something you hand coded or have you been using a library ? If it's a library you might want to look at the documentation to see how the weights are formatted.

Comment: Hi Dear Dolma, thanks a lot again, i did it but again gave me incorrect answers. differences between testing answer and answers of formula that I wrote are more.i test both approaches you proposed but no achievement was gotten. i think another parameter or key are here that i don't know. have you ever done it?(deriving formula was built from activation function(transfer function), weights and biases)

Comment: Yes if these two approaches don't work it might mean that there is something more to it. But you can't know what it is unless you know how your model has been implemented. What language are you using ? With which API/toolbox ?

Comment: i using the neurosolutions software for this simulations.it is a common software in ANN modeling and its document are more in net. i read related topic in weights series. after that, i wrote a code by Matlab language to have formula but...

Comment: sorry, i read exactly last relation of yours first comment again , for output layer you didn't add to bias, is it right? we must only multiple to weights? and didn't use of activation function in output layer? are them right? i should use it or you forgot it?

Comment: Well usually people don't use biases or activation functions in the output layer, but here again it depends on the implementation of the solution you're using. When I mentioned "your code", I meant the code used to train the network, not the one you used afterwards. Since you're using a software you can only rely on the documentation to know how the data is formatted. This is why it's usually better to use open source APIs or even hand code everything yourself, at least you know what it's doing and how to use it. Now all you can do is hope the documentation for your software is detailed enough

Comment: well i used feedforward multilayer perceptron model. it used activation function for output layer and also i used it in my code. really i don't know what to do. it seems everything is right but doesn't show correct answer. you know when i test my formula with testing data(that used to test the neural network into software itself) it show 2% difference. is it ok? is it usual?

Comment: Hi Dear Dolma, have you Skype account?, we can discuss on it more easy

Comment: Hi Dolma, is it possible if want to send me your code (ANN formula)? i want to compare my code with yours, maybe i could find my mistake. you know it is about 2 weeks that i stopped at it. or i send you my code to you see, my email address is davidmurphy26@ymail.com