# the mathematical function that relates a given output to three inputs through artifical nural network analysis

Tags: neural-network

I have a data set with three input variables and one output. I want to fit the target column to the input data using an artificial neural network with one layer, for example. My concern is, can I obtain a closed form or analytical formula that links the modeled target to the three input variable? Please let me know whether the software can process that.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can always translate a one-layer neural net into a closed form solution. Let's call your input variables x, y, and z, your bias node b, and the connections between them and your output cx, cy, cz, and cb respectively. Once you've trained the neural network so that the connection weights are adjusted, the output value should equal x*cx + y*cy + z*cz + cb. (technically the bias term is b*cb, but b = 1).

If you were using a more complicated neural network, this equation would get a lot more complicated, particularly as you add hidden layers, but theoretically you can always write it out analytically. It just won't always be tractable to evaluate the analytic form.

For a more detailed answer, see: [Deriving equation by weights and biases from a neural network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510098/deriving-equation-by-weights-and-biases-from-a-neural-network)